# Sharepoint Multi level approval with reject back to prior level

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, nintex-workflow

I am trying to put a nintex workflow for a multi level approval with reject back one level. Ex a task goes for an approval to group A , if anyone from A approved the task moves to group B and so on. But if group B rejects them the task should fall back to person who approved from group A , if group C rejects then task should fail back to person who approved in group B. 
Can someone help me on this please ?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use state machine control and place the approval task under it and change state after action.

If A approves it goes to B, but if B rejects it will capture rejectipn comment and change state to approval A.

Go through the documentation of State machine on nintex.